# Output open() file to specific folder rather than directory of 'mu' interface

Tags: python-3.x, file, raspberry-pi

I've created this script for logging data to file from python (raspbian with Arduino & DHT-11 for trying out serial port in python) and displaying it and logging it with time stamp on each line and appending the sensor data to a text file. The thing is that I want this text file to be in some other directory than this python editor. Thanks in advance

> Currently this thing outputs the weather_data.txt to /home/pi/mu_code
>   I want this to output the text file to /home/pi/shared/Weather

```
x = (f"{str(localtime().tm_mday)} - {str(localtime().tm_mon)} - {str(localtime().tm_year)}")

with open(x + ".txt", "a") as weather: #making/opening the .txt file
    print(strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p", localtime()) ,end="", file=weather) #adding timestamp to file
    print(f" :: T =  {t}°C - rh = {rh}%", file=weather) #adding data to file
```

I need this with open() command to create a *.txt in "/home/pi/shared/Weather" rather than "/home/pi/mu_code"

Comment: Please go through this blog first may be this can give you a hint of your problem https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution after some research.
we can add the path as string and append it to file name, ie:

rather than asking to create **weather.txt**, we can ask *open()* to create **/home/pi/shared/weather.txt** and it'll create the file in */home/pi/shared/* folder.